# Please How to fix "Invalid use of group function"

Tags: mysql

I try to use nested CASE WHEN syntax in SUM() function but nothings works since 3 days

When I retrieve all sum and nested conditions the code work great

I explain:

- Table contrat: Each client have a contract in which this two values: Prix_TTC (the price of the article), Qac_cont (The quantity of the article client must consume each month)
- Table commande: Each client order article with quantity (Quantite_cmd)

So what I try to do is to get all financial loss for each client during the actual month and SUM all these amount

```
SELECT 
    SUM(pertes) AS pertes_reelles
FROM
    (SELECT 
        c.ID_clt,
            SUM(CASE
                WHEN
                    ((co.Qac_cont - SUM(CASE
                        WHEN Quantite_cmd IS NULL THEN 0
                        ELSE Quantite_cmd
                    END)) * - 1) < 0
                THEN
                    ((co.Qac_cont - SUM(CASE
                        WHEN Quantite_cmd IS NULL THEN 0
                        ELSE Quantite_cmd
                    END)) * - 1)
                ELSE 0
            END) * co.Prix_TTC AS pertes
    FROM
        clients c
    LEFT JOIN contrat co ON co.clt_ID = c.ID_clt
    LEFT JOIN commande cmd ON cmd.clt_ID = c.ID_clt
        AND MONTH(DATE(cmd.date_livr_cmd)) = MONTH(DATE('2019-08-30 09:23:23'))
    WHERE
        c.Etat_clt <> 'D'
    GROUP BY c.ID_clt) AS liste
```

Comment: Can you provide more info of what you are trying to acquire? Perhaps a sample data could help.

Comment: Okay Let me edit

Comment: I think the issue is that you are multiplying the SUM with `co.Prix_TTC`, so breaking the aggregation. Try to test with the inner select only to see if you can get it to select what you want..

Comment: @Adder with the `c.ID_clt` only in the inner select all works, but when I try with the actual request without ` * co.Prix_TTC` it doesn't work

Comment: Those nested SUM() invocations look questionable to me.

Comment: @BobJarvis you think? Why?

Comment: @BobJarvis you right, but please how to obtain what I wan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @BobJarvis says, the problem was with the nested SUM so I have broken down nested processing and it WORKS Thanks ! the new request :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
                WHEN
                    perte < 0
                THEN
                    perte * - 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS pertes_reelles
FROM
    (SELECT 
        c.ID_clt, co.Prix_TTC, ((co.Qac_cont - SUM(CASE
                        WHEN Quantite_cmd IS NULL THEN 0
                        ELSE Quantite_cmd
                    END)) * - 1) as ecart, co.Prix_TTC * ((co.Qac_cont - SUM(CASE
                        WHEN Quantite_cmd IS NULL THEN 0
                        ELSE Quantite_cmd
                    END)) * - 1) as perte
    FROM
        clients c
    LEFT JOIN contrat co ON co.clt_ID = c.ID_clt
    LEFT JOIN commande cmd ON cmd.clt_ID = c.ID_clt
        AND MONTH(DATE(cmd.date_livr_cmd)) = MONTH(DATE('".$today."'))
    WHERE
        c.Etat_clt <> 'D'
    GROUP BY c.ID_clt) AS liste
```